# JavaScript auto-incrementing a variable in jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I have JavaScript using jQuery and AJAX which creates a dynamic array, which has some values used for AJAX request as below;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var array = Array("y","y","x","y","y","y");
function updateBackground(cellId, titleId) {
    var i = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {
          filename: Array(array[i], "testdata", $("#"+titleId).html())
        },
        success: function(response){
          $("#"+cellId).css("background-image", "url('pdfthumb/" + response + "')");
        }
    });
i++;
}
</script>
```

The script is suppose to submit values in the array in `array[i]` for each AJAX request. I made a variable `var i` which auto increments.. But the script is not working.. The script works well if `array[i]` is replaced by `array[0]` or `array[1]` etc..

How can I solve the syntax error?

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? What exactly is Happening ?

Comment: I think its due to closure. Try `var i = 0;` before the `updateBackground` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it... Thank you so much @Jed, @Pointy, @Crozin, and @Lord Vader for helping me to figure it out.... :)

I just take `var i = 0;` outside the loop.... above `var array` like;

```
var i = 0;
var array = Array("y","y","x","y","y","x");
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `updateBackground()` i = 0 (again). May be you must initialize i outside of the function.

What happens if   `i > array.length`? And I would rename the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an iterator. Your variable i gets set to 0 every time the function runs. The increment at the end is useless.

Maybe you need something like this?

```
var array = Array("y","y","x","y","y","y");
function updateBackground(cellId, titleId) {
    for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {
              filename: Array(array[i], "<?php echo $dir; ?>", $("#"+titleId).html())
            },
            success: function(response){
              $("#"+cellId).css("background-image", "url('pdfthumb/" + response + "')");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If he intends to be able to access "i" in the "success" function, then this just will not do.  There's only one "i", and it's shared by every "success" handler created in the loop.

Comment: He's not using i in success, though?

Comment: your code is cool.. but it is not working for first array element, ie, array[0] and all others works well..

Comment: Yes @Jed, that's true in this example. My note was intended as a caution only.

Comment: Thank you @Crozin, your code is cool.. but it is not working for first array element, ie, array[0] and all others works well..  I got my error n it is fixed... I take var i outside the loop :)

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `updateBackground()` function, the `i` variable is being reinitialized. It's just a local variable and as soon as the function finishes it's being destroyed by GC. You could do something like this:

```
var UpdateBackground = {
    array: [..],
    counter: 0,

    doUpdate: function(cellId, titleId) {
        // AJAX request

        this.counter++;
    }
};

UpdateBackground.doUpdate(1, 1);
UpdateBackground.doUpdate(1, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you @Crozin I got it n fixed... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should send the whole array maybe as a commaseparated string and instead and make just one ajax request, because http-requests are expensive and change the server side code accordingly. And fetch the cellids as an array. 
If you think that you have a long list or a table it can be like a lot of requests. Do the stuff in client code and do the stuff in server code and keep the number of http-requests as few as possible.

And use the join method on the array.

```
    var arr = [ 'y', 'y' ]; 
    arr.join(','); 
// outputs y, y
```